# Update all record from UTC to EST timezone + mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I trying to update a all the time present in my database to which is UTC to EST format basically -05:00

First Query
I running the following query

```
update time_info set time = SELECT CONVERT_TZ(time,'+00:00','-05:00');
```

Now this doesnot seem to work

Now There is other way I can achieve this is something like

```
update time_info set time = time - 5*3600;
```

But I was thinking just for sake of learning is it possible to run the first query as expected

Comment: How have you defined the column? How timezones are handled depends on the column type.

Comment: No It just a `datetime` field but I knew all time are UTC format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `DATETIME` column, you can use the `CONVERT_TZ` function to convert time zones. Just don't use the `SELECT` keyword:

```
update time_info set `time` = convert_tz(`time`, '+00:00','-05:00');
```